# How to Alert the user when a specific Input to an array is less than or equal to a variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

How would you alert the user if a specific finishing time is equal to the records which are constants. An example of it would be "John" having a time of 9.76 which is less than the current world record, then a print command would inform the user that an athlete has met the world record. An explanation of your finding would be helpful.

```
import time
datasets= []
world_record = int(9.76)


for i in range(0, 8):
    print("Inputting Data for Lane", i)
    gender = str(input("Is the athlete male or female ")) 
    athlete = str(input("What is the athletes name "))
    finishTime = float(input("What was the finishing time "))
    dataset = [gender, athlete, finishTime]
    datasets.append(dataset)
    if finishTime == float("10"):
        print("A world record has been reached")

print("{0:<10}{1:<10}{2:<15}".format("Gender","Athlete","Finish time"))

ds = sorted(datasets, key=lambda x:x[2], reverse=False)

for s in ds:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("{0:<10}{1:<10}{2:<15}".format(s[0], s[1], s[2]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`world_record = int(9.76)` is rounding down to 9, keep it as `world_record = 9.76`

then check if the finish time is less than the record

```
for i in range(0, 8):
    print("Inputting Data for Lane", i)
    gender = str(input("Is the athlete male or female ")) 
    athlete = str(input("What is the athletes name "))
    finishTime = float(input("What was the finishing time "))
    dataset = [gender, athlete, finishTime]
    datasets.append(dataset)
    #check if the world record has been met
    if finishTime == world_record:
        print("A world record has been met")
    elif finishTime > world_record:
        print("A world record has been beaten")
        print("the new world record is {}".format(s[2]))
        world_record = finishTime
```

OR

```
for s in ds:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("{0:<10}{1:<10}{2:<15}".format(s[0], s[1], s[2]))
    if finishTime == world_record:
        print("A world record has been met")
    elif finishTime > world_record:
        print("A world record has been beaten")
        print("the new world record is {}".format(s[2]))
        world_record = finishTime
```

In both cases, I am assuming you want to update `world_record` if this is not the case omit `world_record = finishTime`

Comment: I should of mentioned that I have tried this, How would I do it to a specific set of data within the array. As up to 8 entries will be in the array.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to check if one specific person beat the record, or do you want to check if any person has beat the record?

If it is one specific person do you know their index in the array or their name?

Comment: I would like for it to alert the user, when any person has beat the record and tell the user their name. For e.g. John has broken the current world record.

Comment: the answer has been updated, on another note, the input() returns a string in python3 so you do not need to surround it with str()

Comment: The code only affects the last inputted finishing time

Comment: How would I make it so that it would compare the record with every finishing time recorded and then output the individuals who have beaten the record

Comment: you need to put the if statement in the for the loop. i omitted it due to brevity, but have updated it now